# Mouse drag event has Y coordinate jump/gap

Tags: javascript, dom, events, mouseevent, svelte

Why is there a gap in the drag event?

Here's the working example: https://svelte.dev/repl/e62f83d69cea4fda9e8a897f50b5a67c?version=3.31.1

*Note: the console.logs in the REPL itself slow down the events, so it may not be noticeable.

I get the following logs:

```
dragstart 78

drag 64    <--------- how does this happen?

drag 81
drag 82
drag 83
drag 84

drag 0
dragend 0
```

```js
on:dragstart={(e) => {
    mouseYCoordinate = e.clientY;
    console.log('dragstart', mouseYCoordinate);
}}

on:drag={(e) => {
    mouseYCoordinate = e.clientY;
    console.log('drag', mouseYCoordinate);
}}

on:dragend={(e) => {
    console.log('dragend', mouseYCoordinate);
    console.log('\n');
}}
```

This gap causes the items to flicker.